# eclipse not recognizing maven project as java

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have downloaded a fresh copy of Eclipse IDE for Java Developers for Mac Cocoa 64-bit running on my macOS High Sierra 10.13.1

I have a maven project (not an eclipse project) which I have cloned into a directory within my eclipse workspace.

I have gone to `file -> import -> existing maven projects` and imported it.

However, eclipse doesn't recognize anything as java, when I right click on any folder and go to 'build path' everything is greyed out.

How do I get it to recognize that I have a java project? I have tried many of the fixes I have seen online but nothing seems to work. Also, shouldn't it recognize it as java out of the box? It's a valid maven project imported into an IDE explicitly for java developers?

Many thanks!

EDIT: If I run `mvn clean install` at the command line, the build succeeds so I don't think there's anything wrong with the maven side of things.

EDIT: I tried the suggestion from @pobu of running `mvn eclipse:eclipse`. This completes successfully but doesn't appear to create any new files. There is this line in the output that suggests it's not running properly:

```
[INFO] --- maven-eclipse-plugin:2.10:eclipse (default-cli) @ acsohn ---
[INFO] Not running eclipse plugin goal for pom project`
```

Comment: Have you try to run mvn eclipse:eclipse? It will create configuration files based on your pom.xml and environment settings

Comment: Thanks @pobu. Please see my latest edit.

Comment: Note: Eclipse Photon is 5 releases out of date. Eclipse 2019-09 (4.13) is the current release.

Comment: Thanks @greg-449. 2019-09 is what I have. I saw the list of releases in wiki and thought that Photon was the latest name covering all the latest releases since Photon, but I guess they've abandoned their astronomical terms.

Comment: Don't use maven eclipse plugin (as suggested by pobu). That thing is obsolete and has been replaced by m2e. You will make a mess out of your project by mixing them together.

Comment: Another thing -> AFAIK cloning into workspace is considered bad practice (not sure what was the technical reason behind that... something with file watches i guess). You should have your clone outside and import it as external maven project.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I've figured out what it was, by creating a working maven java project in eclipse and then comparing it with what I have. Turns out for some reason I had

`<packaging>pom</packaging>`

in my pom.xml whereas the successfully imported project had

`<packaging>jar</packaging>`

Not sure how `pom` got in there or why it has to be `jar` if I don't care about the packaging but I guess perhaps eclipse looks at this to figure out if it's a java project?

Comment: When you  have `<packaging>pom</packaging>` it means that it is a parent project. As you have a one-module project, it will not work. `<packaging>jar</packaging>` instructs Maven to build project and the result will be a jar file.

Comment: @menteith This is overly simplified. You can build a single project with packaging pom without problems, but it will result in a pom only, no packaged artifact will be produced. This can be useful for various reasons, parent POMs, BOMs etc.

Comment: Perhaps it could be useful but clearly this is not OP wanted.